# SBT task to download / fetch a file from a URL

Tags: sbt

What is a recommended way to write an SBT task that downloads a file from a known URL into a local file?

Older versions of SBT provided `IO.download` which could be used to download a URL into a local file, but in recent versions (1.2.8) this method is not available and seem to be [commented out](https://github.com/sbt/io/blob/c2668e77443e2a6fd7c33da706c299bf5a795e69/io/src/main/scala/sbt/io/IO.scala#L421) in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Process.html):

```
import scala.sys.process._

url("http://...") #> file("somefile") !
```

Comment: Now at https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Process.html