# Include Resources from an External Repository in Sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a centralized repo maintaining a set of proto files used across a multitude of projects. I want to be able to download this into my resources before the ScalaPB compiles proto into corresponding case classes. I've seen some examples using dependsOn, but this repo is not a sbt project.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider defining a custom task to [download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55434312/5205022) files into local resources directory like so

```
lazy val remoteProtoFiles = taskKey[Unit]("Download proto files from remote repository into local resources directory")
remoteProtoFiles := {
  import scala.sys.process._
  streams.value.log.info("Downloading proto files from remote repository into local resources directory...")
  val externalResources = "https://my-external-repo/protofiles/"
  val protoFiles = List("foo.proto", "bar.proto")
  val resources = (Compile / resourceDirectory).value
  protoFiles.foreach { protoFile =>
    url(s"$externalResources/$protoFile") #> (resources / protoFile) !
  }
}
```

and then have `compile` task [depend on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44669226/5205022) `remoteProtoFiles` task like so

```
compile in Compile := (compile in Compile).dependsOn(remoteProtoFiles).value
```

Now executing `sbt compile` should download proto files into `yourProject/src/main/resources` before compilation executes.