# Use SBT to download / use file from URL

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

My goal is simple: download an external file at build-time and include it in an SBT-packaged artifact.

I have been looking or a way to fetch data based on a `URL` and use the local `File` as the source in a `Univeral / mapping` (see [sbt-native-packager Universal plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#universal-plugin-getting-started-with-packaging)).

Is it possible to make SBT *(1.x)* do this natively at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SBT task to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434130/sbt-task-to-download-a-file)

Comment: @GaëlJ great find! Leaving out the "task" keyword must have caused me to not find that question. It answers 90% of what I asked for, closing this.