SBT plugin or similar workaround to download a zip file from the remote location during the compile time
I currently looking for a sbt-plugin or workaround to download a zip file from a remote location as a separate task during the compile. I tried sbt-unzip plugin but, I don't want to extract the zip file. only want to download it. Does anyone know any plugin related to that or related implementation ?

You can implement it without the need for a plugin if it's just to download a file. Using a curl command from a custom task for instance. I may provide an example on Monday.

This may help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434130/sbt-task-to-download-fetch-a-file-from-a-url
